# Multiplying numbers in two arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to multiply the numbers of two arrays in java. I declared two array objects. a for getting xValue and b for getting yValue.. After putting values of x and y for n programs each time value of x and y should be multiplied. Please show me the code..
import java.util.*;

```
public class DataSetTesterN {   
   public static void main(String[] args)   
   {   
       DataSet a = new DataSet();
       // Object "a" for xValue"
       DataSet b = new DataSet();
       // Object "b" for yValue"
       Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("enter the total number of Programs");
       int m =input.nextInt();
              for(int i =1; i <=m; i++)
                  // Entering total number of tested program.
                                 {
           System.out.println("enter x value for the program no. "+i+"");
           a.add(input.nextInt()); 
           // Getting an input for xValue.


           System.out.println("enter y value for the program no. "+i+"");
           b.add(input.nextInt());  
           // Getting an input for yValue.


           }



      System.out.println("count x: " + a.getCount());
      System.out.println("count y: " + b.getCount());  

      System.out.println("Mean x: " + a.getMean());
      System.out.println("Mean y: " + b.getMean()); 

      System.out.println("Sum x: " + a.getSum());
      System.out.println("Sum y: " + b.getSum()); 

      System.out.println("standard deviation: " + a.getStandardDeviation());  
      System.out.println("standard deviation: " + b.getStandardDeviation()); 



}  
}
```

/////////////////////////////

Class for DataSet

```
import java.util.ArrayList;   
import java.util.List;   


public class DataSet {   

    private List<Double> inputList = new ArrayList();   
    double x = 0;   

    public DataSet() {   
    }   

    public void add(double x) {   

        inputList.add(x);   

    }   


    public double getMean() {   

        double sum = getSum();   
        double count = getCount();   
        double mean = sum / count;   

        return mean;   

    }   

    public double getSum() {   
        double sum = 0;   

        for (double d : inputList) {   
            sum += d;   
        }   
        return sum;   
    }   

    public double getStandardDeviation() {   


        double sum = getSum();


        double mean = getMean();   
        double calc1 = 0;   
        double calc2 = 0;   
        double count = getCount();   
        double stdDeviation = 0;   

        //System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);   

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {   
            calc1 = inputList.get(i) - mean;   
            calc1 = Math.pow(calc1, 2);   
            calc2 = calc2 + calc1;   
        }   

            calc2 = calc2 / (count-1);   
            stdDeviation = Math.sqrt(calc2);   
        return stdDeviation;   
    }   

    public int getCount() {   
        return inputList.size();   

    }   
}
```

Actually I want to make formaula. I want to get value of x*y , x^2 and y^2.
I am very sorry I am new to JAVA language and dont know how to do that.

Comment: What is DataSet? And how do you want to multiply your array? Please post an example.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiply the numbers of two array"? This can be interpreted in several different ways - please give an example.

Comment: "I declared two array objects" - can't see them in the code-sample...

Comment: Thanks guys sorry I am new to JAVA. I have updated the code. Please tell me how can I solve me problem.

Comment: Actually I want to make function to input data of x and y for n program. I need some basic multiplication and sum of the values. Please check the following image showing the data I need to calculate on my program.
http://i16.photobucket.com/albums/b50/ejaz2006/exc.jpg

Comment: Anyone !!! who can solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Being so new to java, you use arraylist's to do simple arithmetic? What is this used for?